# How to accept *.csv format input file cross browsers?

Tags: html, safari, cross-browser

I'm using:

```
<input type="file" accept=".csv" />
```

It working on Chrome, Firefox, IE 10+, but not working on Safari.
And I try with:

```
<input type="file" accept="text/csv" />
```

It just working on Safari.
Help me to cross browsers for it.
Thanks.

Comment: Since you did it twice, are you aware accept is spelled "accept"?

Comment: Sorry about my typos. Currently, I'm using accept=".csv", it no working on Safari.

Comment: As of the time of this comment, Safari "supports the type format (e.g. image/*) but not the extension format (e.g. .png)". See [caniuse accept](http://caniuse.com/#feat=input-file-accept).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Just use comma for that )

```
<input type="file" accept=".csv, text/csv" />
```